# How to pass state up to Router component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

I'm pretty new to React and I'm trying to create a simple game. All the data is in state in **App** component. I want to redirect page to **Battle** component with couple of props using Router. Can I pass state from App up to the Router so Router can pass it down to Battle component like this:

```
<Route path="/game/battle" component={
  <Battle
        monster = {this.props.details} //some props living
        team = {this.props.team}       //in App component
        player={this.props.player}     //can i pass it here somehow?
      }
  />
```

Components look like this:
**Router => App(state) => Battle**        and somewhere after onClick(change path) i **want Router => Battle(with data from App state) => return to App after battle**. Is there a way to achieve it?
Thanks to everyone interested

EDIT render prop fixed the issue, thanks. Router renders data passed via props but is it a good idea to pass data from other component state to Router like this:

```
<App  //this is where state with monster, team, player lives
 (...)
  <Router
        monster = {this.state.details} //some props living in this App component
        team = {this.state.team}       //can i pass it to Router somehow
        player={this.state.player}     //so Router renders Battle component 
                                       //with monster, team, player data?
      />
/>
```

EDIT 2
Ok, so Im trying to place `Router` component inside App component and pass some props to it from `App` state. In this `App` component also I change path to `/battle` using onClick. In `Router` I pass props using render props but it crashed app for good. I guess I messed something up...

Router.js:
(...)

```
      <Route path="/game/:storeId" component={App} />

      <Route
       path="/battle"
       component={() => (
      <Battle
          player={this.props.player}
          team={this.props.team}
          monster={this.props.monster}
      />
      )}/>
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
(...) export default Router;
```

App.js:

```
(...)
  state = {
    player: {},
    monsters: {},
    locations: {},
    team: {},
    battleMode:  false,
    communicate: "asdad",
    merchants: {},
    quests: {},
    items: {},
  };

(...) return(
                      <Router
        monster= {this.state.monster} //some props living in this App component
        team = {this.state.team}       //can i pass it to Router somehow
        player={this.state.player}     //so Router renders Battle component 
                                       //with monster, team, player data?
                />
          <button onClick={()=>{this.props.history.push(`/battle`)}}>Go →</button>

(...) 
)
```

Solution: follow this sandbox, it's great:
[codesandbox.io/s/cranky-keller-hbig1?file=/src/App.js](http://%20codesandbox.io/s/cranky-keller-hbig1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [render prop](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Route/component)

```
<Route
  path="/game/battle"
  render={() => (
    <Battle
      monster={this.props.details}
      team={this.props.team}
      player={this.props.player}
    />
  )}
/>
```

---

Alternatively you can still use `component` prop but this will cause mounting of new components

```
<Route
  path="/game/battle"
  component={() => (
    <Battle
      monster={this.props.details}
      team={this.props.team}
      player={this.props.player}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, i can render data i pass as props now, but how to pass data from App to Router, where monster, team and player lives? I guess that's not how its suppose to be done, but I'd like to do somethinkg like this: 

return ( <Router
                          monster={this.props.details}
                          team={this.props.team}
                          player={this.props.player} /> )

Comment: _this is_ how you pass data from `App` to the `Battle component` - you do not directly pass it to `Route` - you pass it to the component that gets rendered when the route matches the current path. However, on your edit it looks like you are specifying that `monster`, `team`, and `player` are states. Therefore when passing down as props to `Battle` you should pass down like this --> `this.state.team`, for example - not `this.props.team`. Back on the Battle component, it should already receive that state as props - so just go ahead and access them via `this.props.team`

Comment: Thanks, could you catch a glimpse at edit2, please?

Comment: in Router.js, do you export a component named `Router`?

Comment: ya I export deafult. Like this: (...)   
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  )
      }
    }
export default Router;

Comment: This will help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-keller-hbig1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it took me a while but I did manage to implement it thanks to Yours sandbox, thanks a million!